# what does IBM DB2 z/os JDBC emulateParameterMetaDataForZCalls do?

Tags: jdbc, db2, zos

When i use IBM data Studio to connect to our db2 v8 z/os database the JDBC connection url generated is this.

```
jdbc:db2://host:port/LOCATION:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;emulateParameterMetaDataForZCalls=1;
```

contains this parameter setting: `emulateParameterMetaDataForZCalls=1`

What does this setting do? Why do i need it?

Comment: I think it's a valid question, so the close vote is not warranted -- the parameter in question is undocumented, so simple googling does not help find an answer.

Comment: correct, i just spent half a day trying to find out what this does, and couldnt find any useful info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This parameter enables the use of the method `PreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData()` against a DB2 for z/OS data source.

Comment: Mustaccio, thanks very much, thats cleared that up :-)